# How to replace repeating values with NULL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables invoice and invoice_has_items. When I join those two tables I receive data from both tables:

[image: 1]

here first three columns are from invoice table. I want to replace those duplicate values to 0 or null like this.

[image: 2]

My query is:

```
SELECT inv.*,invHas.* 
FROM invoice inv,invoice_has_item invHas 
WHERE invHas.invoiceID=inv.id
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you send the query you use to join the tables?

Comment: SELECT  inv.*,invHas.* 
FROM invoice inv,invoice_has_item invHas
WHERE invHas.invoiceID=inv.id;

Comment: This is not a job for SQL but it can be easily done in the client code (I guess it can be done in MySQL using subqueries and variables but it is an ugly solution). But in order for it to work you should order the rows by the first and probably the fourth column. Otherwise the database is not required to return the rows in any specific order and then your requirement doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes it can be done using the client code. But I needed to be done this because I already have completed that and this was a requirement change. I'm passing the query and get results. Thats why i was looking for something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a ranking and then a conditional statement:

Something like this:

```
SELECT IF(rank=0, invoice_id, '-') AS invoice_id,
       invoice_item_id
FROM
    (SELECT inv.id AS invoice_id,
            invHas.id AS invoice_item_id,
            @rank:=CASE WHEN @invoice <> inv.id THEN 0 ELSE @rank+1 END AS rank,
            @invoice:=inv.id AS clset
     FROM invoice inv,
          invoice_has_item invHas,

         (SELECT @rank:= -1) r,

         (SELECT @invoice:= -1) i
     WHERE invHas.invoiceID=inv.id
     order by inv.id, invoice_has_item.id
     ) AS ranked;
```

The idea is to rank the output of your initial query and then change the output based on the rank. In this case the rank should increase for every item in the invoice and reset when the invoice id changes.

The solution is untested since no ddl is given.